# How to form Splunk query to split a field into separate fields as per the maximum number of partitions?

Tags: split, splunk, splunk-query

I have some strings like below returned by my `Splunk` base search.

```
"CN=aa,OU=bb,DC=cc,DC=dd,DC=ee"
"CN=xx,OU=bb,DC=cc,DC=yy,DC=zz"
"CN=ff,OU=gg,OU=hh,DC=ii,DC=jj"
"CN=kk,DC=ll,DC=mm"
```

Note: CN,OU,DC could be 0 or many.

My ultimate goal is to find all OUs something like below.
(The combinations also need to be unique.)
(All blank lines can be excluded.)
eg:

```
bb     (blank)
gg      hh
(blank) (blank)
```

The query that am using currently is not nice and it is not generic.
It will work if at least one of my split results into 5 parts (0,1,2,3,4).
But, it will not work and give blank results if none of my split results into 5 parts (0,1,2,3,4) i.e. all of them result in less than 5 parts.

```
index=xx sourcetype=yy
| fields s
| rex field=s mode=sed "s/,DC=.*//g"
| eval temp=split(s,",OU=")
| eval a=mvindex(temp,1)
| eval b=mvindex(temp,2)
| eval c=mvindex(temp,3)
| eval d=mvindex(temp,4)
| dedup a b c d
| table a,b,c,d
```

How to make it generic i.e. get the count of split and make fields as per maximum split length?

Comment: You could find the unique values using for example a pattern like `(OU=([a-z]+)\b)(?![\s\S]*\1)` https://regex101.com/r/41bspj/1 if lookaheads are supported. The values are in group 2

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: Its working on the regex tool, but on splunk may be it needs some reformatting as per SPL. Because am getting this error: Error in 'rex' command: The regex '(OU=([a-z]+)\b)(?![\s\S]*\1)' does not extract anything. It should specify at least one named group. Format: (?<name>...). 


 Meanwhile, I found this in splunk answers, which is working on SPL.

 index=xx sourcetype=yy
 | fields s
 | rex field=s max_match=0 "OU=(?<OU>[^,]+)"
 | eval OUs=mvjoin(OU, ",")
 | dedup OUs
 | table OUs

Answer (score 1):

The `rex` lines to extract these things should look something like the [following](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/SearchReference/Rex) (note: `\w+` matches on the character class "word characters" which are `[A-Za-z0-9_]`):

```
| rex field=s max_match=0 "CN=(?<cn>\w+)\,?"
| rex field=s max_match=0 "OU=(?<ou>\w+)\,?"
| rex field=s max_match=0 "DC=(?<dc>\w+)\,?"
```

This should make multivalue fields in each event for all of the `cn`, `dc`, and `ou` entries

You can then `split` them apart as [needed](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#split.28X.2C.22Y.22.29), eg:

```
| eval cn=split(cn,"split string")
```